# Docker container is exiting immediately

Tags: docker, dockerfile

using 
`docker run -it -v /root/apache-cassandra-3.9:/root/apache-cassandra-3.9 --name=cassan_8 cassan_8`
but exiting immediately, no errors in events.
Image is created from dockerfile

`[root@ip-10-0-1-186 ~]# cat Dockerfile
FROM centos:6
RUN yum install -y httpd
RUN yum install -y centos-release-scl
RUN yum install -y python27
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk
ADD apache-cassandra-3.9/bin/cassandra /usr/local/bin
ADD cassandra.sh /usr/local
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/cassandra.sh
EXPOSE 7000 7001 7199 9042 9160
WORKDIR /root/apache-cassandra-3.9/bin
CMD ["/usr/local/cassandra.sh"]`

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-186 ~]# cat cassandra.sh
#!/bin/sh
/root/apache-cassandra-3.9/bin/cassandra -R & >> naresh.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `cassandra` as the entry point, but you're also sending it to the background:

```
/root/apache-cassandra-3.9/bin/cassandra -R & >> naresh.txt
```

Therefore, this line immediately returns. For Docker, as soon as the command has finished, the container has fulfilled its purpose, and therefore, the container is shut down.

Possible approaches to prevent this:

- keep cassandra in the foreground by omitting the `&` (assuming that cassandra keeps running in the foreground and doesn't fork)
- add another command at the end of your `cassandra.sh` that never returns (a good candidate is `tail -f <some logfile>`)
- wait for cassandra with `waitpid`

**UPDATE**

The advice regarding *wait for cassandra* is incomplete; a complete minimal solution would be:

```
/root/apache-cassandra-3.9/bin/cassandra -R & >> naresh.txt
childPID=$!
wait $childPID
```

(I stole this idea from [the startup script used in the official Docker images for Oracle RDBMS](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/dockerfiles/12.2.0.1/runOracle.sh))